# If an abstract class can't be instantiated, why is the following possible?

Tags: java, abstract-class

In the following code a Graphics object is passed into the following paintComponent method, which is then cast into a Graphics2D object. Isn't Graphics an abstract class so why is the following possible?

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
 Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
 Font font = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 15);
 comp2D.setFont(font);
 comp2D.drawString("Potrzebie!", 5, 50);
}
```

Comment: You're not instantiating a graphics object in this code. You're receiving an instance of some concrete subclass.

Comment: Nowhere do you see `new Graphics()` in your code above, so nowhere are you instantiating a pure Graphics object. Instead somewhere in the bowels of Swing a `new ConcreteGraphicsImplementation()` object (whatever it is named) is created. Since this object must be OS specific, it is likely has "native" code, usually C or C++, that you can't see.

Comment: You might be confusing casting with conversion.  When you're working with primitive types, a cast actually converts the value from one type to another, so you get a new value.  When you're working with reference types, a cast just checks the class of whatever object you're casting, then lets you refer to it differently - it doesn't actually change the object or make a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a class can't be instantiated doesn't mean you can't get an instance of it.

In your example, all you are doing is casting it to a different class which is in the Graphics hierarchy.

Here's an example.

```
    public class AbstractDemo {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Concrete c = new Concrete();
          AClass a = (AClass) c;
          a.me();
       }

    }

    abstract class AClass {
       public void me() {
          System.out.println("Abstract parent");
       }
    }

    class Concrete extends AClass {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A class being abstract just means that you can't create such a class directly.  Once you have such a class, you can cast it to make it appear like it is any of its subclasses.  In other words, all "abstract" means is that you can't do:

```
SomeAbstractClass obj = new SomeAbstractClass(...);
```

You can have a reference to a `Graphics2D` object, like in your example, but if you ask Java to tell you the real type of the object, it will never actually be a `Graphics2D` object. From this code, you can't be sure that the real type of the object in question is a `Graphics` object either.  That could again be a reference to a subclass of the real object, like maybe `MyGraphicsObject`, or something like that.

This is the whole point and the power of polymorphism.  Once you have an object created, it will behave like any of its subclasses and can be treated as though it is a pure instance of any of those subclasses through upcasting.

Here's some code that points out what happens to the identity of an object that is upcast:

```
abstract class Abstract {
    public void whatAmI() {
        System.out.println("I'm Abstract");
    }
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
    @Override
    public void whatAmI() {
        System.out.println("I'm Concrete");
    }
}

public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This won't compile.  That's what it means for "Abstract" to be abstract.
        // Abstract abs = new Abstract();

        // You can create a Concrete, and then upcast it to an Abstract reference...
        Concrete concrete = new Concrete();
        Abstract abs = (Abstract)concrete;

        // But it's stll really a Concrete
        System.out.println(abs.getClass().getName());

        // And it will still act like a Concrete if Concrete has overridden one of Abstract's methods.
        abs.whatAmI();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
org.littleshoot.proxy.inlet.Concrete
I'm Concrete
```

Note that if you ask Java the type of the object, it's still Concrete even though you've asked for the type of an object via an Abstract reference.  Also note that if you call a method on the Abstract class that has been overridden in Concrete, it is Concrete's version that will be called.